# After Effects Script - Expression Controller Coordinates

Tags: javascript, expression, extendscript, after-effects

Writing a script for After Effects 2015. Trying to copy coordinate data from a point expression controller to a layer's position data. I can't seem to find a way to point to the Expression Controller values.

```
for (i = 1; i <= app.project.activeItem.selectedLayers[0].property("Effects").numProperties;  i++) {
    app.project.items[2].layer(i).property("position").setValue(app.project.activeItem.selectedLayers[0].property("Effects").property(i).value);                         
}
```

I've also tried this:

```
for (i = 1; i <= app.project.activeItem.selectedLayers[0].property("Effects").numProperties;  i++) {
    app.project.items[2].layer(i).property("position").setValue(app.project.activeItem.selectedLayers[0].property("Effects").property(i).property("Point").value);                         
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm hoping I didn't make any typos...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you going. You need a layer with an expression point controler and it needs to be selected. I'm using here the match names of the effects. You can use the names from interface as well. I suggest getting the [rd_GimmePropPath script from redefinery.com](http://www.redefinery.com/ae/view.php?item=rd_GimmePropPath). Helps me every time.

```
function main() {
  app.beginUndoGroup("XXX");
  var curComp = app.project.activeItem; // get the current comp
  if (!curComp || !(curComp instanceof CompItem)) {
    // doulble check
    alert("noComp");
    return;
  };
  var layerwithpointcontroller = curComp.selectedLayers[0]; // the first selected layer
  // get the value of the expression controler
  var pointvalue = layerwithpointcontroller.property("ADBE Effect Parade")
    .property("ADBE Point Control")
    .property("ADBE Point Control-0001")
    .value;

  $.writeln(pointvalue); // take a look at it
  var nullobject = curComp.layers.addNull();// add a null
  nullobject.position.setValue(pointvalue);// set its position
  app.endUndoGroup();
}
main();
```

Comment: Thanks! This was a huge help!

Comment: Thanks again. I think I accepted it...still getting used to SE